# Oracle 10 xmltype extract where clause

Tags: sql, oracle10g, extract, xmltype

I'm trying to extract a given set of values from an xmlfield blob data type.

The Xml structure looks like

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>   
    <ItemParameters type="**XYZ" version="000000000">
<Attribute name="Item ID" elementaryType="Numeric">
    <Value value="12"></Value>
</Attribute>
<Attribute name="A" elementaryType="B">
    <Value value="50"></Value>
</Attribute>    
</ItemParameters>
<Scales>
</Scales>
```

where I'd like to check if attribute name = A and elementryType = B and extract the value beneeth in this case 50.

I tried doing like

```
select xmltype (dynamic_data).EXTRACT ('//ItemParameters/Attribute/Value()').getVal ()
```

Which is not working

Comment: "Which is not working" means what? What error does it result in? What output does it give you? What output do you require it to give you?